# Minimizing Mfc application with open Qt dialog

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-mfc-migration

I am using QtWinMigrate solution to show dialogs from my plugin dlls that are loaded in third party Mfc application. The problem is the following :

When I minimize the main window of my Mfc application, and when I restore it back again, all of my open Qt dialogs are lost. I found out that actually my Qt dialogs are destroyed i.e destructors are called.

I did some debugging and discovered the following :

When I close my Mfc main window my Qt dialog gets WM_SHOWWINDOW message with SW_PARENTCLOSING wparam parametar. Then QtWndProc is called, which for the SW_PARENTCLOSING case issues sends QHideEvent:

in QtWndProc() function in file qapplication_win.cpp line 2160

```
case WM_SHOWWINDOW :

if(lparam==SW_PARENTCLOSING) {
   QHideEvent e;
   qt_sendSpontaneousEvent(widget,e);
   widget->hideChildren(true); ////////////////////
```

and the eventFilter  of QWinWidget sends DefferedDelete who deletes my dialog :

in QWinWidget.cpp in line 280

```
QWinWidget::eventFilter(OObject* o, QEvent* e){

    case QEvent::Hide: 

    if(w->testAtrribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)

    deleteLater();
```

}

Can someone please explain this behavior to me? This seems like bug to me .

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to use QtWinMigrate with a plugin DLL also.  While I can get a Qt Window to appear the window is completely unresponsive as if it's not getting any events (while the MFC app remains responsive).  Did you ever encounter this or have an input on how to solve it?

Comment: I am only showing QDialog windows from my plugin dll. I am not sure if u can show QMainWindow. However check if you set the message hook appropriately. Set breakpoint in QtFilterProc in qmfcapp.cpp and see if it gets hit. This function sends the windows messages to Qt for processing.

Comment: Also when creating the qt dialog set its parent window to be the main window of the host MFC application.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question. See the documentation on [WA_DeleteOnClose](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum). You will need to call [setAttribute(WA_DeleteOnClose, false)](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qwidget.html#setAttribute) on your dialogs that you don't want deleted when they are hidden.